# error: expression must have integral or enum type

Tags: c, cuda

In CUDA C, why does the following code

```
findMinMax<<sizeof(lum)/1024,1024>>(lum,&min_logLum,&max_logLum);
```

give this error?

```
error: expression must have integral or enum type
```

Comment: Your code may be wrong on many more levels. It is very likely that after addressing the issue this question is about, you will encounter run-time errors and crashes. You may want to refer to CUDA samples which come along with the SDK, as well as this example, for a typical paradigm of a kernel launch: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use *triple* angled brackets as part of kernel launch syntax:

```
findMinMax<<<sizeof(lum)/1024,1024>>>(lum,&min_logLum,&max_logLum);
```

That should resolve compilation error, provided the rest is correct (e.g., the set of arguments matches the kernel prototype).

Note that a few other things are suspicious in the way you launch the kernel:

- You round the number of blocks per grid down instead of up. For example, if `sizeof(lum)` evaluates to 1500, you still launch only 1 block of 1024 threads. This may not be what you intend to do.
- You pass host pointers `&min_logLum` and `&max_logLum` to the kernel, which, again, may be not what you intend to do here, however it is hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: OMG OOPS!!! That's such a misleading error message, though. Why can't the compiler tell me the chevrons are messed up? Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @RenéG because the compiler sees valid syntax when it encounters <<  and >>. Because of the missing angled brackets your launch configuration becomes a sequence of operator calls (<<, >>, ","). The compiler does a semantic check on the operands of the expressions and then it recognizes the error which is provided. Compilers may give you a hint what you could have meant from the context of the error (clang for example does this).